# How do I follow tags?

Tags: support, tagging, tag-watching

How do I follow particular **tags** for new questions asked with this tag?

Answer (score 4):

(1) You can subscribe to a tag (to get emailed a list of questions that come up each day in the selected tag), and

(2) you can also designate your watched tags, which are then highlighted in light-yellow in the list of of all questions.

To do either, you need to go to your profile page and select the third tab from the left:  "Edit profile and settings".

(1) On the menu to the far left, note the blue subtitle "Email settings".  Click on the option "Question subscriptions".  For each tag you select, a list of questions asked will then be sent to your email account each day.  (Unless you want a flooded email inbox, use this sparingly.)

(2) On the menu in the left-most column, again, using the tab "Edit profile and settings", below the blue subtitle "Email settings", there will be "Tag watching & ignoring". Click on it, and to the right of that, there'll be two headers called "Tag Watching" and "Ignored Tags".  Questions in the tags you add under "Tag Watching" will be highlighted, then.

---

Note: you can also "ignore" tags you choose to ignore.  Questions using any tag you choose to ignore become barely visible in the questions lists.

You can add any tag you want to ignore under the "Ignored tags" header just as you do for adding tags under the "Watched tags" header as in (2) above.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and create filters. For example, I created a filter called `Matrices`:

[image: Questions list filtered by the [matrices] tags and sorted by "newest" on stackexchange.com.]

I am notified whenever new questions on matrices are posted on a total of 11 SE sites:

[image: Filter details, showing which tags are followed and on which sites.]

Comment: This makes it very easy to detect cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [other answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27864), you can change this in [/users/preferences](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences). Another way to change the watched tags is editing the tags directly in the sidebar on the right. Alternatively, you can use the tooltip of a given tag.

I will quote from: [What do “watched tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)

> To watch a tag, do one of the following:
>
> - In the tag’s tooltip, click on the "Watch Tag" button.
> - On the main page’s sidebar, click on *Watch Tag*
> - On the main page’s sidebar, click on *edit* next to *Watched Tags*
> - On [`/users/preferences`](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences), use the respective field in the *Tags* section.

In the tooltip displayed when you hover above a tag, on the bottom left you can see the "Watch tag" button with the symbol of an eye next to it, and on the bottom right you can see the "Ignore tag" button with the [*no symbol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) next to it. By clicking on these buttons, you can toggle the watching/ignoring status of the tag. You can also click on the RSS button on the top right corner if you want to add an RSS feed of the recently active questions in that tag.

[image: Tooltip seen on hovering over a tag.]

If you look in the sidebar on the right, you should see list of your watched tags and ignored tags (possibly empty). By clicking on "edit", you can add some new tags to your watched tags and ignored tags.

[image: Sidebar showing "Watched tags" and "Ignored tags".]

Answer (score 0):

The best and my favorite way is `RSS` that I wonder nobody mentioned it before. Just hover on the tag you want to follow it and press the RSS icon on the top right of appeared tip:

[image: Circle and arrow pointing out the RSS button on the top right corner of the popup that appears upon hovering over a tag.]

Comment: Perhaps no one mentioned it before because Google tried to kill RSS back in 2013.

Comment: If I may ask, what RSS reader do you use?

Comment: [feeder rss](https://feeder.co/)