# A cyan background for any question

Tags: discussion, support, tag-watching

I wanted to understand why I see some of the questions in cyan as in the attached image. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You had clearly designated one of more of the the tags of the highlighted question as favorite tags..  This can be done on the "edit profile" tab of your profile, where you can select favorite tags, and questions with that (those) tags will appear highlighted, in the form you outline in red. You can also choose to "ignore tags", in which case, they will appear highly faded among other questions.

Comment: It is clear.  It will also assist users looking to quickly identify questions, among the list, that are in their favorite topics.

Comment: There are several posts on this site which has newer information about this feature. (Since this post, it was renamed and many other things have change. Perhaps this could be closed as a duplicate - it seems that there is more than one possible duplicate target: [What is the significance of the yellow highlighting on some items in the list of MSE questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34613) and [Why are some questions highlighted in a light blue, on the main site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28768)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Since this was posted, the feature was renamed from *favorite tags* to *watched tags*. You can find links to some additional information [in the tag-info for tag-watching](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-watching/info) and also in various posts with this tag both [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-watching) and [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-watching).

---

The questions which are in different color are those ones, which have one of your [favorite tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/favorites/info).

From [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173):

> - Questions with these tags become highlighted on the front page.

- Questions with new activity are shown on [stackexchange.com/filters](//stackexchange.com/filters/).
- In the review queues, questions from these tags are shown to you before other questions.

The actual color is different for various sites - it depends on the design and color scheme of the actual site. For example, it is different also here between the main site and meta.

More about adding (or removing) a tag from the list of favorite tags: [How do I follow tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863)

Comment: Thanks for confirming all I said in my comment.

Comment: @amWhy Feel free to post an answer. (If you think this is duplicitous, I can simply remove mine.)

Comment: Since I have answered basically the same question on the neighbor site, I copied the answer - with some minor modifications: [Pink questions in the list](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3349).

Comment: No, this is fine.  It gives the question an answer.

Comment: @Martin, do you know that "duplicitous" is not related in meaning to "duplicate"? It means "deceitful".

Comment: @GerryMyerson No I did not know the difference between [duplicitous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicitous) and [duplicate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicate). (I would not be surprised to find out that this is a frequent mistake by people who do not speak English as their first language.)  All the more reason to delete this answer, if it can be considered deceitful. :-)