# Why are some questions highlighted in a light blue, on the main site?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I notice that some questions are highlighted in a light blue (cyan), on the main site.

Is this a new feature? And what does it mean?

Does it mean, that someone is writing an answer/comment or is modifying the question in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [A cyan background for any question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28476).

Comment: @MartinSleziak  The main thing that has changed since your answer to the linked post is that instead of selecting "favorite tags", a user can select the tags they are interested in "watching"...  "ignored tags" are still "ignored tags", and can be selected on the same webpage as one selects tags for watching.  Don't know why we couldn't have simply kept "favorite tags"...?

Comment: @amWhy Exactly as you say, the feature has a new name. It was announced here: ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any question you see with blue highlighting is a question using one or more of the tags you've favorited, which now means a tag which you are watching.  The highlighting is to help point out questions to you that may of be greater interest to you, given your preference expressed for the tags you selected.

It might appear like a "new feature" to you, if you have previously, but recently, selected "tags" to watch. What is highlighted is usually going to vary from person to person.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I cant remember I have selected any "tags to watch".

Comment: Click on your profile, then click on the tab in the upper left corner "edit profile and settings." On the left-hand side, you'll see a number of selections.  Under "email settings" you'll see "tag watching and ignoring".  Click on that:  You'll likely see a list of all the tags that you are "watching" and all (if any) tags you are ignoring.  "Watching tags" is a relatively recent term on the site, changed from the same feature formerly known as "favorite tags"

Comment: An even easier way select tags to  "watch" or "ignore" is now possible by hovering over any tag selected in questions, or by  hovering over any tags you want to watch (tab on main page: "tags"), and you'll get a pop-up option in which you can choose to "watch tag" or "ignore tag"; ignored tags mean questions with that tag will be somewhat greyed out on the main site; they are still accessible to you, but they aren't as prominent as regular questions, or highlighted questions.