# How to subscribe to a tag?

Tags: support, feature-request, tagging, tag-watching

Since some time, I have been unable to subscribe to a tag I'm interested in, so that I get emailed new questions in such a tag.

I have found some posts about subscribing, the ones with the most recent activities are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/370706), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863/288417).
All of them mention a very simple way to subscribe a tag via email: just click the `subscribe` button in the tag's tooltip.

> But in any tag's tooltip I no longer see any `subscribe` button!

If I've already subscribed to a tag via email, then in the tag's tooltip I see a `manage subscription` button, but in this way I cannot get a new subscription to a tag. As a workaround, I can add a subscription from my own `network profile` page, but it is not the same and, in my opinion, it is very clumsy.

I'm aware that it is still possible to subscribe a tag via RSS, or to watch a tag, but they are not the same.

Is there still an easy way to subscribe a tag via email? If not, I guess [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) in the Help Center should be updated.

Comment: I think you should be able to create some kind of email subscription using [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/370392/my-filter). See also this post on MathOverflow Meta: [Tag subscriptions and “Watch tag”](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3910).

Comment: This post on Meta Stack Exchange might also be useful: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135)

Comment: @MartinSleziak - Thank you for the link! This is essentially what I meant when I said that there is a workaround from the personal network profile, but having a precise link to refer to is much better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid this actually changed and the answer is that (at least currently) this is not possible. See ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching)

The option to subscribe is not supported anymore. Instead one *will* be able to chose to get notifications in  ones inbox (not yet operational though!).

It is still possible to get email notification about inbox messages. Thus, indirectly (get inbox notification, get email about inbox notification) it still will work but it does not yet and it will not be in near real time.

As explained on the linked to post this is intentional and it is thus unlikely that the functionality will be restored. It seems at the moment the way to go for this is via RSS feed.

As for the documentation, indeed, this should be update. SE controls these pages centrally. I assume they will do this at some point. Maybe once the notifications are implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my opinion, the fact that the option to subscribe via email is not supported anymore is a pity, especially now since the new notification system is not working yet.

Comment: Yes, I can see how it is convenient especially for more rare tags. I was surprised that it was removed. It seems the issue was that it was too resource intense for not enough in return.